# How do I edit my code to make the 'next' button lead to a blank page IN THE SAME WINDOW? (not a new window )

Tags: python-3.x, oop, tkinter, canvas, screen

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Frame, BOTH
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk

#Welcome screen

root = Tk()
root.configure(bg = "steel blue")


canvas = Canvas(root, bg = "steel blue", highlightthickness = 0)
canvas.config(width = 350, height = 250)

#canvas.config(width = root.winfo_screenwidth(), height = root.winfo_screenheight() )
canvas.pack()

#Making of the round rectangle

class Rectangle:

    def round_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, radius=25, **kwargs):

        points = [x1+radius, y1,
                  x1+radius, y1,
                  x2-radius, y1,
                  x2-radius, y1,
                  x2, y1,
                  x2, y1+radius,
                  x2, y1+radius,
                  x2, y2-radius,
                  x2, y2-radius,
                  x2, y2,
                  x2-radius, y2,
                  x2-radius, y2,
                  x1+radius, y2,
                  x1+radius, y2,
                  x1, y2,
                  x1, y2-radius,
                  x1, y2-radius,
                  x1, y1+radius,
                  x1, y1+radius,
                  x1, y1]

        return canvas.create_polygon(points, **kwargs, smooth=True)

    my_rectangle = round_rectangle(10, 60, 330, 250, radius=20, outline = "black", fill="white")

canvas.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5,anchor=CENTER)

def UserIdentification():
    newWindow = Toplevel(root)

Next_button=Button(root,text = "Next", anchor = W, command = UserIdentification)
Next_button.configure(width = 10, bg = "black", fg = "blue" ,borderwidth = 4)
Next_button = canvas.create_window(150, 200, anchor=NW, window=Next_button)

canvas.create_text(170, 100, text = "Hey there, welcome to DeliverToday! \nWe bring your needs right at your doorstep ~ \nhave a great journey ahead!")  

root.mainloop()
```

Hi, so the code above works completely but I am confused on how to make the "Next" button create a new blank screen(which I will design later but blank for now to make it less complicated). I cant use top-level because I don't want a whole new window to open up but I want it to open in the same window (one screen to exit and another to open). How do I do that with a very easy code?? (the button is on a canvas)

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://www.homeandlearn.uk/python-database-form-tabs.html#:~:text=TKinter%20Form%20Tabs&text=Tabs%20are%20called%20Notebooks%20in,add%20tabs%20to%20that%20Notebook.&text=In%20between%20the%20round%20brackets,us%2C%20that%27s%20the%20main%20form.). Does it help?

Comment: By "blank screen" do you mean you want a screen without the canvas, or do you want to keep the canvas but delete everything on the canvas?

Comment: The form tab site may help me later on as I continue to add things to the blank screen, but not with this particular question to create a blank screen, sorry!

Comment: By 'blank screen' I mean a screen with a canvas because I will still need some squares with text in them and stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete everything on the canvas with the `delete` method. If you pass it the literal string "all" it will delete everything on the canvas.

```
def UserIdentification():
    canvas.delete("all")
```

Comment: Oh that helps thank you!! Just a quick question thought for further reference because I am trying to make a basic app with multiple screens so what if I wanted a screen without a canvas (say if that particular screen only contains text or sth)?

Comment: @khushi: then just destroy the canvas and add something else.

Comment: Oh ok! Thank you so much!!